# Time difference between rows pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a time variable in my dataframe and I am trying to come up with a new column that gives the time passed in minutes from one row to another. I was trying to use this function:

```py
df["Time"].diff()
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
> ```

Is there any way I can create a column in pandas with the time difference from one row to the next one?

Comment: Can you share some examples of the "Time variables"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `Time` column to `datetimes` with default same `date`, so [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) working well:

```
df['difference'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"].astype(str)).diff()
```

Comment: Can you explain why that should work? How can `diff()` work on a datetime.time type once converted to string?

Comment: I tried it and it worked perfectly thank you! had to modify a bit to have it as a new column, but thank you very much

Comment: @NataliaCaceres - You are welcome, code is edited for assign to column